# I cant understand this lastindexof method in Java 11

Tags: java, lastindexof

```
    int a="abcd".indexOf("d",0);
    int b="abcd".indexOf("d",1);
    int c="abcd".indexOf("d",2);
    int d="abcd".indexOf("d",3);
    int e="abcd".indexOf("d",4);
    int f="abcd".indexOf("d",5);




    int b1="abcd".indexOf("d",-1);
    int c1="abcd".indexOf("d",-2);
    int d1="abcd".indexOf("d",-3);
    int e1="abcd".indexOf("d",-4);
    int f1="abcd".indexOf("d",-5);


    System.out.println("Last index of from index 0 "+a);
    System.out.println("Last index of from index 1 "+b);
    System.out.println("Last index of from index 2 "+c);
    System.out.println("Last index of from index 3 "+d);
    System.out.println("Last index of from index 4 "+a);
    System.out.println("Last index of from index 5 "+f);


    System.out.println("Last index of from index -1 "+b1);
    System.out.println("Last index of from index -2 "+c1);
    System.out.println("Last index of from index -3 "+d1);
    System.out.println("Last index of from index -4 "+e1);
    System.out.println("Last index of from index -5 "+f1);
```

Results

```
Last index of from index 0 3
Last index of from index 1 3
Last index of from index 2 3
Last index of from index 3 3
Last index of from index 4 3
Last index of from index 5 -1
Last index of from index -1 3
Last index of from index -2 3
Last index of from index -3 3
Last index of from index -4 3
Last index of from index -5 3
```

Can someone explain how positive and negative index work?

Comment: For your purposes have a look at [lastIndexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) because the [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) works differently

Comment: 0-4 is the starting index it'll look for the char d and return 3. 5 is outside the array bounds and will return -1. Any negatives basically start from index 0.

Comment: Oops . My question is about lastindexof.

Answer (score 1):

It is not spelled out for `indexOf(String, int)`, but [`indexOf(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,int)) behaves the same way (emphasis mine):

> There is no restriction on the value of `fromIndex`. **If it is negative, it has the same effect as if it were zero: this entire string may be searched.** If it is greater than the length of this string, it has the same effect as if it were equal to the length of this string: -1 is returned.

(Note that your text talks about `lastIndexOf`, but the code is `indexOf`. The logic for `lastIndexOf` is reversed: whereas the whole string is found after any negative index, none of the string is in front of a negative index, so `lastIndexOf` with a negative starting point will never find anything.)

Comment: Ok my mistake. My question is lastindexof

Comment: String str="this is how";

        int a0=str.lastIndexOf("is");

        int a=str.lastIndexOf("is",0);
        int b=str.lastIndexOf("is",1);
        int c=str.lastIndexOf("is",2);
        int d=str.lastIndexOf("is",3);
        int e=str.lastIndexOf("is",4);
        int f=str.lastIndexOf("is",5);




        int b1=str.lastIndexOf("is",-1);
        int c1=str.lastIndexOf("is",-2);
        int d1=str.lastIndexOf("is",-3);
        int e1=str.lastIndexOf("is",-4);
        int f1=str.lastIndexOf("is",-5);

Comment: System.out.println("Last index of from index 0 "+a0);

        System.out.println("Last index of from index 0 "+a);
        System.out.println("Last index of from index 1 "+b);
        System.out.println("Last index of from index 2 "+c);
        System.out.println("Last index of from index 3 "+d);
        System.out.println("Last index of from index 4 "+a);
        System.out.println("Last index of from index 5 "+f);

Comment: System.out.println("Last index of from index -1 "+b1);
        System.out.println("Last index of from index -2 "+c1);
        System.out.println("Last index of from index -3 "+d1);
        System.out.println("Last index of from index -4 "+e1);
        System.out.println("Last index of from index -5 "+f1);

Comment: Last index of from index 0 5
Last index of from index 0 -1
Last index of from index 1 -1
Last index of from index 2 2
Last index of from index 3 2
Last index of from index 4 -1
Last index of from index 5 5
Last index of from index -1 -1
Last index of from index -2 -1
Last index of from index -3 -1
Last index of from index -4 -1
Last index of from index -5 -1

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Delete this question. Added new modified

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63172394/i-cant-understand-this-lastindexof-method-in-java-11-version2

Comment: I explained for `lastIndexOf` as well. Please read my answer again. There is nothing special about negative starting position. Also, if you need to add extra information, edit the question, don:t add 3 code comments.