# I cant understand this lastindexof method in Java 11- version2

Tags: java, lastindexof

```
public class Test2{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str="this is how";

    int a0=str.lastIndexOf("is");

    int a=str.lastIndexOf("is",0);
    int b=str.lastIndexOf("is",1);
    int c=str.lastIndexOf("is",2);
    int d=str.lastIndexOf("is",3);
    int e=str.lastIndexOf("is",4);
    int f=str.lastIndexOf("is",5);




    int b1=str.lastIndexOf("is",-1);
    int c1=str.lastIndexOf("is",-2);
    int d1=str.lastIndexOf("is",-3);
    int e1=str.lastIndexOf("is",-4);
    int f1=str.lastIndexOf("is",-5);

    System.out.println("Last index of from index 0 "+a0);

    System.out.println("Last index of from index 0 "+a);
    System.out.println("Last index of from index 1 "+b);
    System.out.println("Last index of from index 2 "+c);
    System.out.println("Last index of from index 3 "+d);
    System.out.println("Last index of from index 4 "+a);
    System.out.println("Last index of from index 5 "+f);
    System.out.println("Last index of from index -1 "+b1);
    System.out.println("Last index of from index -2 "+c1);
    System.out.println("Last index of from index -3 "+d1);
    System.out.println("Last index of from index -4 "+e1);
    System.out.println("Last index of from index -5 "+f1);
}
```

}

Results

```
Last index of from index 0 5
Last index of from index 0 -1
Last index of from index 1 -1
Last index of from index 2 2
Last index of from index 3 2
Last index of from index 4 -1
Last index of from index 5 5
Last index of from index -1 -1
Last index of from index -2 -1
Last index of from index -3 -1
Last index of from index -4 -1
Last index of from index -5 -1
```

Comment: I cannot understand your question, whats the problem, what are you trying to do?

Comment: It is well explained in the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String,int))

Answer (score 1):

`int lastIndexOf(str, fromIndex)`: Returns the last occurrence of str, starts searching backward from the specified index “fromIndex”.

**Example:**

```
String char1 = 't';
String str = "test";

int index = str.lastIndexOf(char1); // Will return index = 3
int index_b = str.lastIndexOf(char1, 2) //Will start search backwards from letter 's' and return index_b = 0
```

It's well documented [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-lastindexof-method-example/)

Comment: what is -ve index? I see the second argument in positve index as substring 0-lastindex then search. Question what is negative index means?

Comment: This dont make sense at all.  String str="this is is how";         int e=str.lastIndexOf("is",4);
        int f=str.lastIndexOf("is",5);  returns like this Last index of from index 4 -1
Last index of from index 5 5

Comment: You've printed  `System.out.println("Last index of from index 4 "+**a**);` at the fourth line. It should be **e**